# Simplifying Boolean Expressions

Tags: boolean, algebra, proof

I have constructed truth tables to prove that:
 
`ABC + ABC'+ AB'C A'BC = AB+AC+BC`, 
but how do i prove it by simplifying the expression? I'm fairly new to boolean algebra and have tried to use the basic identities to figure it out, but can't seem to get there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't belong as a programming question -- try http://math.stackexchange.com/ possibly, though it may be too basic for there?

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
ABC + ABC'
```

as

```
AB(C + C')
```

Since C + C' is always true, that's just `AB`. The same pattern holds for `AC(B + B')` and `BC(A + A')` being equivalent to `AC` and `BC` respectively.